# Dart Polymer error 'List' is not a subtype of type 'ObservableList' of 'value'

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, core-elements

I am using core-ajax-dart to fetch some data and put it in core-list-dart. And i keep getting this error. I am able to successfully pass heading which is String but I am not able to pass contacts. It fails with the following error

> Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'List' is not a subtype of type
>   'ObservableList' of 'value'.

main page

```dart
<core-ajax-dart auto id="_ajax" url="https://polymer-contacts.firebaseio.com/{{category}}.json" handleAs="json"></core-ajax-dart>
<contacts-page class="page" id="contacts" contacts="{{contacts}}" heading="{{heading}}" flex></contacts-page>
List contacts;
ContactsPage cp = $['contacts'] as ContactsPage;
var ajax = $['_ajax'] as CoreAjax;
    ajax.on["core-response"].listen((event) {
      var detail = event.detail;
      var response = detail['response'];
      cp.contacts = response;
    });
```

element definition

```dart
<div id="title" flex>{{heading}}</div>
<core-list-dart id="list" data="{{contacts}}">
@published List contacts;
@published String heading;
```

Stack trace:

```dart
Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'ObservableList' of 'value'.
Stack Trace:
#0      CoreList.data= (package:core_elements/core_list_dart.dart:48:124)
#1      main.<anonymous closure> (http://localhost:8080/index.html_bootstrap.dart:114:27)
#2      GeneratedObjectAccessorService.write (package:smoke/static.dart:114:11)
#3      write (package:smoke/smoke.dart:34:40)
#4      _updateNode (package:polymer/src/instance.dart:1412:16)
#5      _convertAndCheck (package:polymer_expressions/polymer_expressions.dart:302:16)
#6      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1093)
#7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341)
#8      _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:595)
#9      _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:711)
#10     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:671)
#11     _asyncRunCallbackLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#12     _asyncRunCallback (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:48)
#13     _handleMutation (dart:html:41817)
```

[Almost full source](http://pastebin.com/n1AusufT)

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace to your question? Do you use ObservableList somewhere in your code? Either it's a bug in the elements you are using or the code of your app that causes the problem is missing in the question.

Comment: Added source and stack trace. I am not using ObservableList elsewhere.

Comment: What is`contacts` in `ContactsPage`, can you please add the code line where you declare this field?

Comment: It is mentioned in the element definition 
@published List contacts;

Comment: Can you please try to change `List contacts;` to `var contacts` (main-app and contacts-page) and tell what happens then.

Comment: same error. Have you checked the url if the return is in proper format https://polymer-contacts.firebaseio.com/all.json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70521/discussion-between-maxanderson2011-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data attribute of `<core-list-dart>` requires an `ObservableList` instead of `List`.

What you can do is to change the field to a getter/setter where a passed `List` is automatically converted to a `ObservableList` like

```dart
class Model extends Object with Observable {
// or class SomeElement extends PolymerElement {

  ObservableList _contacts;
  @observable ObservableList get contacts => _contacts;
  set contacts(List contacts) {
    final old = _contacts;
    if(contacts is ObservableList) {
      _contacts = contacts;
    }
    _contacts = toObservable(contacts);
    notifyPropertyChange(#contacts, old, _contacts);
  }
}
```

Comment: I ported the linked app to Polymer.dart https://github.com/zoechi/contacts-app. There is an exception thrown at startup but I couldn't figure out what caused it (debugger doesn't work in my Dart version) but the app seems to work fine so far.

Comment: Wow that was tricky for me indeed. I hope dart guys can make this stuff more simple. Thanks a lot for solving this. Great work on the sample too. I believe you have not added the sass transformer, I do see some stylesheet related warning.

Comment: You are right I didn't add a SASS transformer. I use WebStorm and it did the transformation for me. I was really surprised that `<core-list-dart>` requires an ObservableList instead of just a List. I thought about creating a bug report but I am not sure yet if it's better to support plain lists.

Comment: Also, i was not able to load the json files, it failed with  'Could not find asset' error. But sir, you are the master blaster in dart here. Thank you so much for guiding us through a world which is changing so rapidly(specially polymer ). I really mean it :).

Comment: I couldn't load it from the URL initially used in the source code so I used the file contacts.json (form the web/data directory (I modified the URL of the `<core-ajax-dart>` element) . If you launch the app with `pub serve` (launch from DartEditor) it should work.

Comment: URL gives 404 when using dart stable but works fine with 1.9 dev .

Comment: Did you take a look at https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-core-and-paper-examples/tree/master/web/core_ajax_dart , you know which data type they are using here.

Comment: Obviously not ObservableList but the example uses template repeat not core-list-dart.

Comment: I found that WebStorm serves the page on a different URL. In DartEditor I had to change the URL like `<core-ajax-dart url="/data/{{category}}.json" ...`. I don't know if there is a way to pass a relative URL to `<core-ajax-dart>`

Comment: Why are using di in your project?

Comment: I tried a different approach at first (I usually use route and di together) but dropped it because plain route is way simpler for how this app was built. I removed the redundant dependencies and updated the repo.

Comment: I see. In one of my other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374352/auto-binding-dart-is-not-working-fails-with-bad-state-error/28375442#28375442) you said you liked the polymer-element because it takes care of binding automatically. Why not use the same approach in your sample ?

Comment: I tried to stay as close as possible to the original. Should be easy to switch autobinding-dart to app-element.

Comment: I commited an alternative implementation using `<app-element>` (entry page is `index_app_element.html` instead of `index.html`). The `<app-element>` could also be moved to `lib/elements` - I leave this as an exercise to the students ;-)

Comment: i thought it was due to some design considerations. Will https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.ServiceWorkerClient work as the sericeworker replacement here ?

Comment: I have no idea. I haven't tried anything like this yet.